# Scroll to within popup div with position:fixed

Tags: jquery, overflow, scrolltop

I have a popup with position: fixed. Because I want to disable the body scroll, I have body {overflow-y: hidden}. In the popup I have a lot of content, that's why I have a overflow-y:scroll to the popup and a lot of scroll.

I want to scroll to a specific element in this popup (which has position: fixed and a lot of scroll). I cannot scroll the page to the  tag withing the popup :(

HTML structure is something like this:

```
<body style="overflow-y: hidden;">
    <div class="popup" style="position: fixed; overflow-y:scroll; ... ">
        ....
        ....

        .... really long content
        <h4>here</h4>
        ....
        ....
    </div>
</body>
```

**this is not working :(**

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("h4").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

**Neither this :(**

```
  $('.popup').animate({
        scrollTop: $("h4").offset().top
    }, 2000);
```

**Neither this :(**

```
jQuery.fn.scrollTo = function(where, speed) {
    $(this).animate({
        scrollTop:  $(this).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top + where
    }, speed == undefined ? 1000 : speed);
    return this;
};
$("#custom_development_popup").scrollTo($("h4").offset().top, 300);
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you problem is that you are trying to solve a CSS thing via jQuery (javascript).

Check this fiddle and see if what you are trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/w3QZc/1/

Basically I described the css apart from the div and body tags. You will see that it has no JS. If this is not what you are trying to do please give us more context and explain your question better.

```
body{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.popup{
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: fixed; 
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 30px;
}
```